# How to Bind data to layout objects in Android

Tags: android

I want to create an activity that show informations about a deal, i know how to use JSONParser to retrieve date (like texts and images) in Android but i don't know how to attach these data  to the layout tha i've created which is a complicated layout

Answer (score 1):

You need to access TextViews ImageViews etc. which you created in your Layout.

To do so you need to do something like this.

For example if this is your layout object.

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/my_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Dynamic content gonna get me."/>
```

You can access it in your calling activity like this.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
t.setText("Whatever Dynamic data comes from your source");
```

Also for ImageView you need to do pretty similar stuff.
Assuming that you have your ImageView declared in your layout.

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_imageview);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.random_image);
```

Comment: thanx for this answer but what about an image

Answer (score 0):

Just adding the answer here as I got confused initially after reading the question.
You can attach custom data to Android views using the [setTag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) method. You can store any Object as a tag. To retrieve data use view.getTag and cast it to your stored data type.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a nice binding framework for Android:

http://code.google.com/p/android-binding/wiki/ContactManagerDemo

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/145203/Android-Binding-Introduction

Going to try it now :)